# Hiding the NavBar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to reveal the navbar only when touched at a specific area on the screen.
Is that possible. I was able to hide it. The problem is it could be revealed by touching either the top  or the bottom.

Comment: I believe that is normal operation, otherwise a user wouldn't be able to exit the app activity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the navigation interface out of the way as much as possible, [Sticky Immersive Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#sticky-immersive) is what you're looking for. The user can always swipe on an edge to bring up navigation, but it's transparent and your app will still receive the swipe gesture as if nothing had happened. Access to navigation is always there for the user so they can't be trapped in an app with no way out.

You can add buttons or other controls in your app to show or hide the navigation interface if that's still something you want to do. The Advanced Immersive Mode sample provided with Android Studio shows how.